# Method Call from Java Applet to JavaScript through JSObject doesn't works with IE9 and IE10

Tags: java, javascript, html, web-applications, applet

I'm using JSObject.call to call Java Script API from my applet.
This is working great for Chrome Firefox and Internet explorer v7 and v8.
With v9 and v10 The applet is not working. I can see that it fails when calling JSObject.call and that any API called from the Java Script (which are implemented in the applet) can't be performed (such as myMethod).

From Applet -

```
public void paint(Graphics g)            
{                                                
    if (!appletInit)                         
    {                                            
        try                                     
        {                                                
            window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
            window.call("MyAppletLoad", new Object[0]);                                     
        }                                    
        catch (Exception e)                                    
        {                                                                                 
            e.printStackTrace();                                    
        }                                                                     
    }                        
    appletInit = true;                                    
}
```

In the Explorer debug consol I see this error:

**SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'myMethod'**

In the Java Console I see this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-3" netscape.javascript.JSException: Unspecified error invoking method or accessing property "onAppletLoad"
            at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.newJSException(Unknown Source)
            at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.waitForReply(Unknown Source)
            at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.call(Unknown Source)
            at SmartConfig.paint(SmartConfig.java:239)
            at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
            at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
            at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

line 239 is the line using the JSObject.call:
`window.call("MyAppletLoad", new Object[0]);`

If I set the browser mode to Compatibility view or as older version (8 or lower) it works well.
Is it IE9\10 bug? What is change comparing to IE8?
How can I fix this error?
Please assist.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain the structure of your web page? Where the applet is written and how the JS function `MuAppletLoad()` is defined?

Comment: My Applet is written in java and compiled to a jar. MyAppletLaod() is implemented in the java script file:  applet = document.applets[0];     applet.myMethod () fails.

Comment: solved the issue by adding  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />  to my html. More a workaround then a solution...